# Django: Cannot reference a fieldname in template which contains a dot

Tags: django

The object which I pass from view to template has a few fields which are dynamically incremented and allocated

e.g the object looks like:

```
row = {
 'id':id,
 'input.object1':obj1
 'input.object2':obj2
}
```

I am trying to access the value of "input.object1" as "{{ row.input.object1 }}" in template.
but the page does not show anything for this field (same problem for "input.object2". But "row.id" works fine)

```
{% for row in row_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.input.object1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.input.object2 }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Is there anyway to access these values in html ?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can't we change dot (.) to underscore (_) ? Or make variable name camelCase ?

Comment: If the fields are dynamic why are you referencing them statically in the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following structure of your context:

```
row = {
 'id': id,
 'input': {'object1': obj1, 'object2': obj2}
}
```

which will allow you to access the values the way you try it in your template. But if that structure is dynamic and variable in length, you are better off using a list:

```
row = {
 'id': id,
 'input': [obj for obj in ....]
}
```

and in the template

```
{% for row in row_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
        {% for obj in row.input %}
            <td>{{ obj }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This actually worked. Thanks.
However im stuck at another thing. How can i access the value of that object ?
In the template, can i do something like:  <td>{{ obj.vaue }}</td>     
keeping in mind the previous implementation ?

Answer (score 1):

Django's template languages uses dots in variables names to indicate an index (lists etc), key (dict-likes) or attribute (anything else) lookup, so for `{{ row.input.object1 }}` it first tries to resolve `row.input` as either `row["input"]` or `row.input` - none of which exists.

You want to make `input` either a list or dict, ie:

```
row = {
 'id':id,
 'input'= [obj1, obj2]
}
```

and then

```
{{ row.input.0 }} - {{ row.input.1 }}
```

or

```
row = {
   'id':id,
   'input'= {"object1": obj1, "object2": obj2}
 }
```

and then

```
{{ row.input.object1 }} - {{ row.input.object2 }}
```