# How to print value of a "changing field" in Django template

Tags: python, django, templates

I am trying to display a list of fields (and their values) in a template. 
The problem is that the fieldnames are changing and I dont have control over them.
e,g the fields can be:

```
field_name1
field_object1
field_input1
```

The only thing constant here is the prefix "field_"

This makes a challenge to get the value of that field in the template.
I followed the advice here: [Django: Cannot reference a fieldname in template which contains a dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60809476/django-cannot-reference-a-fieldname-in-template-which-contains-a-dot/60809589#60809589)
and was able to print the field names.
But i still dont know how to print the values of these fields.

model.py

```
rowObj = {
    'id': id,
    'inputList': {'Input_' + k: v for k, v in objList}
    }

# Example of the outputs (The outputs can be one of the following):

    #   rowObj = {
    #         'id': 1,
    #         'inputList': {'Input_Image' : 'http://test', 
    #                       'Input_Image2' : 'http://test2' }
    #        }

#another time the output can be:

    #    rowObj = {
    #         'id': 1,
    #         'inputList': {'Input_Text' : 'Random text', 
    #                       'Input_Text2' : 'Random text 2' }
    #        }
```

My template is:

```
{% for row in row_list %}
      <tr>               
          <td>{{ row.id }}</td>

               {% for obj in row.inputList %}      
                     <td>{{ obj }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
        </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The above code only outputs the field name which would be "Input_Image" and "Input_image2"
I dont know how to print the values of these fields.
Can you please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone on reddit answered this question.
The solution is using the following in template:

```
{% for k,v in row.inputList.items %} {{ k }} : {{ v }} {% endfor %}
```